# AngularJS: giving items in ng-repeat a serialized class

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple ng-repeat, and I would like to create the html with a serialized class like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="item item-1"></li>
<li class="item item-2"></li>
<li class="item item-3"></li>
...
</ul>
```

I can't seem to find how to do it. This is what I've tried so far, among other things:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items" class="item" ng-class="item-{$index}"></li>
</ul>
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `{{$index}}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
class="item item-{{$index+1}}"
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/KA3nn/1/